# How can I sign in to Google inside a Chrome Extension browser_action?

Tags: google-chrome-extension, google-oauth, google-authentication

I’m trying to keep this as simple as possible so that it can be a resource for other people in the same situation.

How can I sign in inside of a chrome extension, which is not a hosted web server?

I seem to get an error “Invalid Cookie Policy” whether I use both the button approach or gapi.load(‘auth2’) followed by gapi.auth2.init(), regardless of including client_id in `<meta>`, manifest.json, and init

If anyone can get it working (sign in and id_token, not the auth token), please leave an answer!

Thank you

Answer (score 1):

I have followed [this](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/tut_oauth) tutorial from official Chrome Documentation and had no problem

Comment: I've done this too, but it's not the same as signing in; it gives an auth token to use the apis, but not an id_token to verify user ←→ google platform ←→ client_id